# Ionic android build fails with Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, babeljs

My app working fine in browser and using Cordova Geolocation as plugin when I start an android build I am getting this error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: [BABEL] /Users/suatkarabacak/Desktop/quarantine/www/2-es2015.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "/Users/suatkarabacak/Desktop/quarantine/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
See "/private/var/folders/2n/czcjwx7554j_h2hpsj53h81m0000gn/T/ng-ZxzGC4/angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
```

From package-lock.json

```
"@babel/preset-env": {
      "version": "7.8.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/preset-env/-/preset-env-7.8.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Rs4RPL2KjSLSE2mWAx5/iCH+GC1ikKdxPrhnRS6PfFVaiZeom22VFKN4X8ZthyN61kAaR05tfXTbCvatl9WIQg==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.0",
        "@babel/helper-compilation-targets": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/helper-module-imports": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/helper-plugin-utils": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators": "^7.8.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-json-strings": "^7.8.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.8.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^7.8.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding": "^7.8.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining": "^7.8.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoped-functions": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-dotall-regex": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-duplicate-keys": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-for-of": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-function-name": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-literals": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-member-expression-literals": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-amd": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-systemjs": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-umd": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-new-target": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-object-super": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-parameters": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-property-literals": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-reserved-words": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-spread": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/types": "^7.8.3",
        "browserslist": "^4.8.2",
        "core-js-compat": "^3.6.2",
        "invariant": "^2.2.2",
        "levenary": "^1.1.0",
        "semver": "^5.5.0"
      }
```

Try to change version of babel but it didn't help too. I am getting too much code on question error but I don't know if there is need for any other explanation so I am writing this sentence.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is how i fixed the exact same exception :

1-Open package.json and add

```
 "resolutions": {
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7"
 },

 "dependencies": {..}
```

2- run `npx npm-force-resolutions`

3- run `npm install`

Now you're good to go..

Comment: Can't try it because I already solve it but if anyone can try and approve the solution I will mark as answer.

Comment: @SuatKarabacak how did u solve this issue? i have tried all the options but none are working for me

Comment: I solved with my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60787422/5229886

Answer (score 6):

Change your tsconfig.json file target value

form
    {
    "target": "es2015"
    }
to
    {
    "target": "es5"
    }

this work for me.

Answer (score 4):

After a few try :

1. Install `npm i @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator`
2. Go to `node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/available-plugins.js`
3. Add `var _pluginTransformNumericSeperator = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator"));`
4. And add `"proposal-numeric-separator":
   _pluginTransformNumericSeperator` to default variable

Comment: This is not a good approach.  you should never modify the node_modules dependencies

Comment: It's a workaround but YES it worked for me after researching many solutions over the internet.

Comment: It is not a good approach because if the author updates the package, then when you do an npm update, your changes will be overwritten.  The correct thing to do is to clone the git repository, make your changes and use your clone in your projects.